# Cant host a FTP Site in IIS

Tags: iis, ftp, directory

I can not host an FTP site via IIS. I am connecting via Windows explorer. I can connected when navigate to ftp://localhost

My error message makes no since.

> FTP Folder Error
>
> Windows cannot access this folder. Make sure you typed the file name
>   correctly and that you have permission to access this folder.
>
> Details: A connection with the server could not be established.

My firewall has a forward set correctly. My windows firewall is turned off. My antivirus is turned off. Authentication is both basic and anonymous. Authorization gives everyone read/write. The folder itself has share on, for everyone.

With FileZilla :

```
Status: Connecting to 76.91.66.31:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command:    USER anonymous
Response:   331 Anonymous access allowed, send identity(e-mail name) as password.
Command:    PASS **************
Response:   530 User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible.

Error:  Critical error
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Comment: Can you use a proper FTP client (not windows explorer) and post the actual connection log? Something like FileZilla client should do the trick.

Comment: make a virtual folder using IIS and try again. if it fails, probably caused by a connection problem.

Comment: Using FileZilla

Status: Connecting to 76.91.66.31:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response: 220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command: USER anonymous
Response: 331 Anonymous access allowed, send identity (e-mail name) as password.
Command: PASS **************
Response: 530 User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible.
Error: Critical error
Error: Could not connect to server

Answer (score 1):

Response: 530 User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible.

Try verifying that the path to the login folder really exists, and that all users that should access it has the proper permissions to list the files in the folder, also I guess you would like to have read access for the files. I don't know if the later one is required over FTP. It shouldn't be nessecary locally, but maybe it matters over IIS FTP.

Try making another account for some higher privileged user with another default login directory and compare your results from there!

Comment: As stated in my original question : Yes, everyone has read/write on both the folder and in IIS